# Highlight Search Term

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way we can set up the highlight functionality to only highlight the words on the page if it matches the exact sentence?

If I try searching for "how do i insure a house", the search results look funky and the highlight functionality spaces out the words.

Output:

[image]

This is my code:

```
  function highlight_search_term_placeholders() {
    static $iter = 0;
    $ret = "|##{$iter}##|";
    $iter++;
    return $ret;
  }
  function highlight_search_term_cb() {
    static $iter = 0;
    $ret = "##{$iter}##";
    $iter++;
    return $ret;
  }
  function highlight_search_term($text){
    if(is_search() && !is_admin()){
      $keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));
      $pattern = '/<[^>].*?>/i';
      preg_match_all($pattern,$text,$matches);
      $placeholders = array();
      foreach ($matches[0] as $v) {
        $placeholders[] = highlight_search_term_placeholders();
      }
      $text = preg_replace_callback($pattern,'highlight_search_term_cb',$text);
      $pattern2 = '/(' . $keys .')/iu';
      $text = preg_replace($pattern2, ' <span class="search-term">\1</span> ', $text);
      $text = preg_replace($placeholders,$matches[0],$text);
    }
    return $text;
  }
  add_filter('the_excerpt', 'highlight_search_term');



function highlight_results_css() {
    ?>
    <style>
        .search-term { background-color:#FF0; }
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head','highlight_results_css');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick'n'dirty: replace

```
$keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));
```

with

```
$keys = get_search_query();
```